# How can I open a url in PhantomJS with Karma and Jasmine?

Tags: jasmine, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

var page = require('webpage').create();

This doesn't work at all. I have wasted hours on trying to simply open a url and test if some text is there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.